# Initialise A Variable With The Output Of A Stored Procedure In MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP]
(
  @CODE CHAR(5)
  , @DESC VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
)
AS
DECLARE @SERVERNAME nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @DBASE nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000)

SET @SERVERNAME = 
  Convert(nvarchar,
  (SELECT spData FROM dbSpecificData WHERE spLookup = 'CMSSERVER'))
SET @DBASE = 
  Convert(nvarchar,
  (SELECT spData FROM dbSpecificData WHERE spLookup = 'CMSDBNAME'))

SET @SQL = 
  'SELECT clnt_cat_desc FROM ' + @SERVERNAME + 
  '.' + @DBASE + '.dbo.hbl_clnt_cat WHERE inactive = ''N''
  AND clnt_cat_code = ''' + @CODE + ''''

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL

RETURN
```

This procedure is used in many different databases and many different servers and is written as dynamic SQL to simplify maintenance. The procedure also runs on a different server than the one the procedure points to.

I want to use the output of this procedure as a value in a table...

```
DECLARE @clid BIGINT
DECLARE @fileid BIGINT
DECLARE @myCode CHAR(5)
DECLARE @myDesc VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @@tempDesc VARCHAR(255)

SET @clid = 1831400022
SET @fileid = 2072551358
SET @myCode = 
  (SELECT _clientPrimBusinessType FROM udbhextclient WHERE clid = @clid)

SET @myDesc = 
  EXEC UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP @CODE = @myCode, @DESC = @@tempDesc OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
  a.clid
  , b.fileid
  , c.usrfullname AS ClientPartner
  , e.usrfullname AS ClientFeeEarner
  , @myDesc AS ClientPrimaryBusinessType
FROM 
  dbclient a
    INNER JOIN
  dbFile b
    ON
  a.clid = b.clid
    INNER JOIN
  dbuser c
    ON 
  a.feeusrid = c.usrid
    INNER JOIN
  udbhextclient d
    ON
  a.clid = d.clid
    INNER JOIN
  dbuser e
    ON
  d._ClientFeeEarner = e.usrid
WHERE 
  a.clid = @clid
  AND b.fileid = @fileid
```

I know this is the incorrect syntax, but you can see what I am trying to achieve this without resorting to temporary tables as this would mean maintenance across 30 different servers with 3 to 5 databases on each.

Smink - Tried your solution and got the following results...

[image: Running Smink's Solution]

Comment: Wow! How do you pronounce this name: UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP

Comment: The Software Package has lots of updates. The update process will delete everything unless it follows the naming convention...
UD - User Defined, SPR - Stored Proc, BH - Boodle Hatfield(employer),PRIM - Primary
BUS - Business
TYPE - Type
STARTUP - Start Up
Some even have a max char length of 15

Comment: Completed answer below. Take a look.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand :I got your message., I will consider it.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand : Thank you so much for your attention. Great master, this change increases the readability of the code. Of course this is my opinion. However, I will respect your opinion. I'm trying to point your attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line:

```
SET @myDesc = 
  EXEC UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP @CODE = @myCode, @DESC = @@tempDesc OUTPUT
```

to

```
EXEC UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP @CODE = @myCode, @DESC = @tempDesc OUTPUT
```

And you have missed assigning `@DESC` in the stored procedure.

```
SET @SQL = 
  'SELECT @DESC = clnt_cat_desc FROM ' + @SERVERNAME + 
  '.' + @DBASE + '.dbo.hbl_clnt_cat WHERE inactive = ''N''
  AND clnt_cat_code = ''' + @CODE + ''''

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@DESC varchar(255) output', @DESC output
```

You should then use `@tempDesc` in the next select:

```
SELECT
  a.clid
  , b.fileid
  , c.usrfullname AS ClientPartner
  , e.usrfullname AS ClientFeeEarner
  , @tempDesc AS ClientPrimaryBusinessType
```

Also your stored procedure allows for SQL injection around:

```
SET @SQL = 
  'SELECT clnt_cat_desc 
     FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SERVERNAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@DBASE) + '.dbo.hbl_clnt_cat
    WHERE inactive = ''N''
      AND clnt_cat_code = @CODE'

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@CODE CHAR(5)', @CODE
```

(Update: Fixed SQL Injection issues.)

Comment: This does return the result but does not put the value in the <select> statement below.

Comment: You should use @tempDesc in the select and not @myDesc. See edited answer.

Comment: Smink - I tried your solution and got the following results... Please see embedded image.

Comment: You are not assigning @DESC inside [dbo].[UDSPRBHPRIMBUSTYPESTARTUP] stored procedure.

Comment: The solution works when you change...
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@DESC varchar(255) output', @DESC
to...
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@DESC varchar(255) output', @DESC = @DESC OUTPUT
Could you edit you answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changed Lord Feature. Have forgot the OUTPUT keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Pheww, I was going crazy on how to do this, I needed to make a result from a stored procedure part of a current query and I was having the hardest time doing this. What I did was wrap Procedure with a function and then return the value and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function (instead of a procedure) that returns a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[my_function]
(
   @par2     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
   @par2     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   @par3     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE 
(
   col1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   col2 NVARCHAR(50),
   col3 NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch your PROCEDURE, you can create a FUNCTION that wraps it and use that wrapper function in queries.